# In SQL how do I match criteria across rows?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

Let's say I have data like:

```
id value
A  X
A  Y
A  Z
B  X
C  X
C  Y
C  W
```

And want to find all id that have both X and Y values or X and W. These are stored in a second table:

```
value1 value2
X      Y
X      W
```

And return:

```
id value1 value2
A  X      Y
C  X      Y
C  X      W
```

This needs to work at scale, where the first table has 100M lines and the second table thousands of rows. I will run in Impala or Hive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `group by`, `having` and some extra logic:

```
select id
from data d cross join
     table2 t2
group by id, t2.value1, t2.value2
having sum(case when d.value = t2.value1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when d.value = t2.value2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```